# Factoring RSA when reusing N

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

Suppose in two RSA instances the same $p,q,N$ are used, but different public keys $a,b$ (and corresponding private keys)

Suppose now we have the two equations

$c_{1}=m^{a} \bmod N$

$c_{2}=m^{b} \bmod N$

Is it possibe to retrieve the original message $m$ with this information?

Comment: You might want to modify the title - this attack would *not* lead to a factorization of $N$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve $m$ if $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

This means $GCD(a,b)=1$. Then, applying the [Extended Euclidiean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) we have $$ax+by=GCD(a,b) = 1$$
Therefore, $$c_1^x.c_2^y = m^{ax}.m^{by} = m^{ax+by} = m\bmod N$$

So just like that, we could recover $m$ but this gives us no information about the factorization of $N=pq$.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to retrieve the original message $m$ with this information?

Well, this is a standard exercise for beginners (that is, you're supposed to learn from it), and so I won't spell out the answer.

I will give you a hint: if you know $N, c_1 = m^a \bmod N, c_2 = m^b \bmod N$, can you compute the value of $c_3 = m^{a-b} \bmod N$?  If so, how could you exploit that?

And, at the end, what condition must exist between $a$ and $b$ to allow you to recover $m$?

Comment: Removed answer so only the hint is left... congrats :)

Comment: in case he wants to see an example.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730675/decrypt-an-rsa-message-when-its-encrypted-by-same-modulus